# Tumblr API get posts ordered by published date

Tags: api, tumblr

I'm facing a problem: I'm using the tumblr api to retrieve my posts but then decided to change the order or my posts so I changed the published date. But when I call the api:

"http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/BLOGTITLE.tumblr.com/posts?api_key=KEY&offset=0&limit=10&callback="

It still get the posts order by ID and not published date.
You'll say I can reorder them but the thing is I have more than 10 posts and I have a load more. So I'll only reorder on the 10 posts and not all of them. For example the last post I created, I would like it to appear at the end so I changed is published date but it still the first object in the Json response.
Anyone know how to get the Tubmlr posts by pusblished date order?
Thanks a lot.
Flo

Answer (score 1):

According to this document : http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#posts, there is no request parameter to define sorting the result.

But, I'm wondering that the posts order by **published date**.

Comment: they are ordered by id. I created several posts then changed the published date of some of them and when I call the API I still get the same list. So I guess it's via id only :/ On their client side (if you look at your name.tumblr.com), it's displayed by publish date though.